# VueJS - Interceptors on long running API calls

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am using vuejs and axios to get information from an external API.

This API needs an interceptor to send an authentication token when I send a POST request.

I created an API.js file that contains the following code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Vue from 'vue'

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8004/'
})

instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    const token = Vue.prototype.$keycloak.token;
    if (token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    }
    return config
}, (err) => {
    return Promise.reject(err)
})

export default instance
```

And everything works fine when I send a request:

```
import API from '../api'
API.post(/intents/)
```

So far so good. However, this request is a long running call, which means that:

1. The client application sends an HTTP request to trigger an
   long-running operation - this is typically going to be limited to
   actions that perform some kind of state update i.e. a POST or a PUT
   request
2. The response will return an HTTP 202 Accepted status, saying the
   request has been queued for processing
3. The response will also include a Location HTTP Header, specifying
   the URI of the status endpoint
4. The client application will poll the status endpoint to retrieve the
   status of the operation (Waiting, Running, Succeeded, Failed etc).
5. Once the operation has completed, the status endpoint will typically
   return another Location HTTP Header, specifying the URI of the
   resulting resource (i.e. the resource that has been created/updated)
6. The client application issues a request to this URI to retrieve the
   resource

In this case, I need to add [This Code](https://gist.github.com/jamesbroome/ff2faad174c69a64486b529cef69a57c#file-axios-pollling-js) inside the Axios interceptor/helper function so that any code that issues HTTP requests will automatically follow the steps above.

Where should I include this code ? On the same file API.js ?

Comment: You can put the polling logic into [response interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors), in API.js

Comment: Hi @Riddhesh, thanks for your reply. I noticed that it uses async. In order add this polling logic into response interceptor, should I start with async function (response) ? on : axios.interceptors.response.use(async function (response) {
    return response;
  }

Comment: yes, I think so